# How does a CursorAdapter load data from Cursor provided by CursorLoader in Android?

Tags: android, android-cursorloader, android-loader

I have implemented the following code to display Contacts as a `ListView`. `MyAdapter` extends `CursorAdapter`.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements 
    LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

    private MyAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView_val);
        adapter = new MyAdapter(this, null, 1);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        .....

        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    } 
        .....
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) { ..... } ....}
```

What I want to know is, how does the `adapter` - `mAdapter` know that it has to pick the data from the `cursor` supplied by the `CursorLoader` (`Cursor` available after calling `onCreateLoader`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.html#onLoadFinished(android.content.Loader, D) here you set the cursor to the adapter by  calling swapCursor

Comment: Can you explain what the purpose of `onLoadFinished` is? I have read it, but it doesn't seem to be quite clear. Thanks in advance!

Comment: OnLoadFinished is called when hmm operation of cursor loading has finished as its name says, now you can pass returned Cursor to the CursorAdapter by calling swapCursor

Comment: Hmm, I got something of it. Anyway, if you do have some links that explain the `Callback` methods in detail, do post here. I am new to Android and it all seems a little confusing.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=cursorloader+example+-stackoverflow&btnG=&client=ms-opera-mini-android&channel=new&gws_rd=cr

Comment: Hey, I got it. Initially while creating the `CursorAdapter` we pass the `Cursor` as `null`, however, in `onLoadFinished` we call `swapCursor` which (I think) **replaces** the initial cursor with the newly passed one. [Here](https://www.grokkingandroid.com/using-loaders-in-android/#how_to_deal_with_cursoradapters) is a good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This link provides with detailed example how the cursor adapter loads the data from cursor loader. Pass through next page also in the web link for the full answer.              http://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/setup-loader.html